does pg_dump provide a consistent value for sequences in postgreSQL (for long running transactions)
When pg_dump captures a full backup, if we have sequences being updated, does pg_dump guarantee that the sequence values will be consistent when the export is being done? To elaborate, if pg_dump takes an hour to run, and if sequences are being updated, are the sequence values consistent with when the pg_dump was executed, or will it be the latest sequence values when pg_dump finishes?
We tried using the set isolation level from one session, and updated the sequence values from another.
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
the above was executed from a session that was kept active.  then from another session, we updated the sequences.
upon checking from the first session, we noticed that the tables that are being updated from the second session don't get the latest changes when isolation level is set.  However, the sequence values are the latest.  What we're trying to understand is whether pg_dump will have the same behavior or not.

In documentation they state: "It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently. pg_dump does not block other users accessing the database (readers or writers)." But there are no more details how it works.

From the source pg_dump:

pg_dump.c
pg_dump is a utility for dumping out a postgres database
into a script file.


Portions Copyright (c) 1996-2023, PostgreSQL Global Development Group
Portions Copyright (c) 1994, Regents of the University of California


pg_dump will read the system catalogs in a database and dump out a
script that reproduces the schema in terms of SQL that is understood
by PostgreSQL


Note that pg_dump runs in a transaction-snapshot mode transaction,
so it sees a consistent snapshot of the database including system
catalogs. However, it relies in part on various specialized backend
functions like pg_get_indexdef(), and those things tend to look at
the currently committed state.  So it is possible to get 'cache
lookup failed' error if someone performs DDL changes while a dump is
happening. The window for this sort of thing is from the acquisition
of the transaction snapshot to getSchemaData() (when pg_dump acquires
AccessShareLock on every table it intends to dump). It isn't very large,
but it can happen.


http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2010-02/msg00187.php

This means that pg_dump takes a snapshot of the state of the database when it commences it's operation. This is what is dumped. Actions happening after the snapshot are the future and are not saved in the dump.
